# How to get the best hyperparameter value after crossvalidation in Pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am doing cross validation on the dataset for some set of hyperparameters.

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1]) \
    .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1]) \
    .build()
evaluator = BinaryClassificationEvaluator()
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=evaluator)
```

I want to know the best value for **regParam** and **elasticNetParam**. In python we have an option to get the best parameters after cross-validation. Is there any method in pyspark to get the best values for parameters after cross-validation?

```
For example : regParam - 0.05 
              elasticNetParam - 0.1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have to fit your CrossValidator first:

```
cv_model = cv.fit(train_data)
```

After you do that, you will have a best_model in:

```
best_model = cv_model.bestModel
```

To extract the parameters, you will have to do this ugly thing:

```
best_reg_param = best_model._java_obj.getRegParam()
best_elasticnet_param = best_model._java_obj.getElasticNetParam()
```

Comment: Can I use best_model._java_obj.getParam('ElasticNetparam')?

Comment: @merkle This works for me after a CV with a Random Forest but doesn't print best hyperparameters after a GridSearch using TrainValidationSplit. It just prints the definition of the hyperparameter in the second case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you've built a logistic regression model using the below arguments.

```
lr = LogisticRegression()
paramGrid = ParamGridBuilder() \
    .addGrid(lr.regParam, [0, 0.01, 0.05, 0.1, 0.5, 1]) \
    .addGrid(lr.elasticNetParam, [0.0, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 1]) \
    .build()
cv = CrossValidator(estimator=lr, estimatorParamMaps=grid, evaluator=evaluator)
cv_model = cv.fit(train_data)
```

You can extract the best model parameters using the following code:

```
print(cv_model.getEstimatorParamMaps()[np.argmax(cv_model.avgMetrics)])
```